# Is it possible to check/get function type or its signature at runtime in SBCL/Common Lisp?

Tags: function, types, runtime, lisp, common-lisp

```lisp
(deftype binary-number-func ()
  `(function (number number) number))

(declaim (ftype binary-number-func my-add))
(defun my-add (a b)
  (+ (the number a) (the number b)))

;; FAIL:
(assert (typep #'my-add 'binary-number-func))
;; Function types are not a legal argument to TYPEP:
;;  (FUNCTION (NUMBER NUMBER) (VALUES NUMBER &REST T))
;;   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]

;; FAIL:
(typep #'my-add '(function (number number) number))
;; Function types are not a legal argument to TYPEP:
;;   (FUNCTION (NUMBER NUMBER) (VALUES NUMBER &REST T))
;;    [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

Is there any way to check the compound type of a function value?
(In Common Lisp, I'm using SBCL sbcl-1.5.0-x86-64-linux)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question. Might be worth explaining your higher level goals though. Would you be better off with generic functions, and in case of performance needs inlining them with `inline-generic-function` or `static-dispatch`? `(defmethod number-adder ((a number) (b number)) (+ a b))`

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure that a function value has applicable signature for the parameters at runtime. (e.g. check `typep` before `funcall` on those) Because I want to deal with multiple different function values that should have same parameter types and return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Common Lisp allows you to write functions even if the compiler can’t determine a smallest function type for them, the compiler is not always able to check if a function has a certain type. Therefore the only sane behaviour is to not check the type.

Secondarily, such a minimal type may not exist. Consider this function:

```
(defun foo (key)
  (getf '(:red 1 :blue 2 :green 3 :yellow 4) key))
```

Does it have type `(function (T) T)` or `(function (T) (or null (integer 1 4)))` or `(function ((member :red :blue :green :yellow)) (integer 1 4))`. Note in both the second and third types are correct but one is not a subtype of the other.

Also note that to check the third type above, one would need to precisely know the behaviour of `getf` which is unlikely to be true in this case and won’t be true at all in the general case.

It is ok for the compiler to check function types because the compiler is allowed to complain or give up. It would be completely unportable for different implementations to have runtime type checking functions which would have quite different behaviours.

Comment: I think this is could be worded better: just because it is not always possible to know the type of something does not mean that it is never sane to check types: for instance the compiler should be allowed to do so as you say.  The last sentence is the key bit: defining what *`typep`* should do is essentially impossible to make portable without defining what type inference the compiler can do which would be a very bad thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, got it.

Comment: But even though, I'm not really thinking that the compiler is doing it hard, because we can express an union types like `(or null integer)` (sth like: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union ) Maybe I'm not really understood your point. Or maybe it's just a design decision of the compiler since precise type inference can slow down its' compiling type.. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, right. Probably I shouldn't ask too much about type on a function value. :-)